# Resource request on algebraic number theory

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

I studied number theory during my master's degree; however, after pursuing my PhD in mathematical logic, I found that my knowledge of number theory has significantly faded. Now, I am interested in rekindling my passion for this field, specifically in diophantine equations rather than prime numbers. Could you please provide me with recommendations for reference books, seminal works, or any other resources that would be beneficial for someone looking to delve back into number theory, particularly focusing on diophantine equations?

Comment: Your question might find a better home on [Math.SE]. MathOverflow is for research-level questions.

Comment: I agree with Alex M. that this question is better suited to math.SE than MO. But I would suggest what I think is an underrated book, namely *A Course in Number Theory* by H. E. Rose. You might also take a look at *An Introduction to Diophantine Equations* by Andreescu, Andrica, and Cucurezeanu, which takes a somewhat unorthodox approach but which definitely focuses on diophantine equations.

Comment: Consider Mordell's *Diophantine Equations*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend *Number Theory*, by Z. I. Borevich and I. R. Shafarevich.  This remains a classic even though Shafarevich expressed some regrettable political views subsequently.  The book contains a particularly nice presentation of the theory of quadratic forms.  The Hasse-Minkowski theorem is one of the major goals of the book.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer

Comment: @Monica: The sentence about Shafarevich's political views is completely unnecessary: if I were you, I would edit the post to eliminate it, and the meaning of the whole post would not suffer a bit.

Comment: @AlexM. It is not *necessary* but it is helpful, at least to me

Comment: It's not helpful because there is a lot of nuance and debate which is completely off topic for here. I am sure many would find his views or writings not regrettable in the slightest.